# jquery css background image works only on firefox

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, setinterval

Could someone point out why this script works only on firefox and not in any other browsers?
Chrome's console showed nothing wrong. Same for firefox's ofc.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

function wrapr(){
    var min=1;
    var max=5;
    var bd = jQuery('body.home');

    function bg(){

        if(min < max){

            bd.css('background-image','url(http://sitename/templates/rt_gantry/images/body/'+min+'.jpg');
            min++;
        }
        else if(min = max){
        min=1;
        }
    }
    setInterval(bg,9000);
}
wrapr();
});
```

Comment: it might help to set it with the problem up in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Have you tried setting `bd` to `jQuery('body')`? You can only have one `body` element, so selecting based on class isn't necessary, and that might be screwing with browsers that don't expect it. Also, FYI your code will display the last image twice as long as the rest.

Comment: Didnt know that about body.Thanks!Removing the class didnt solve anything yet.And yes i know it displays last image twice long,i was planning to fix this later :D

Comment: Trying to eliminate the obvious here - you're not actually using http ://sitename/ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a ')':

```
bd.css('background-image','url(http://sitename/templates/rt_gantry/images/body/'+min+'.jpg)');
```

**Addtionally**: It may be worthwhile for readability to pull out your function definitions:

```
  <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();

    function wrapr(){
        var min = 1;
        var max = 5;
        var bd = jQuery('body.home');

        setInterval(function(){
          if(min < max){
            bd.css('background-image','url(http://sitename/templates/rt_gantry/images/body/'+min+'.jpg');
            min++;
          } else {
            current = min;
          }
        }, 1000);
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      wrapr();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Damn that did it.I was missing the obvius once again..!

Answer (score 1):

This part isn't good:

```
else if(min = max){
   min=1;
}
```

Using a single equals sign results in assigning max to min. You have to use two to check for equality.

```
else if(min == max){
    min=1;
}
```